# Do transistors require heat sink if they are used only as a switch, and not as a dimmer?

Tags: transistors, dissipation

Switching 12V2A, every 2 minutes, TIP122.

Comment: How much power does that transistor burn, what's its maximum allowed temperature, and what are its thermal characteristics?

Comment: What power dissipation did you calculate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TIP122 is a Darlington transistor, which means its VCEsat is around 1 volt, not the fraction of a volt that you'd get with a single bipolar transistor or a MOSFET.

At 2 A and 1 V drop, it will be dissipating about 2 watts.

The TIP122 is available in a TO-220 package, which has a typical allowable dissipation of 2 watts at 25°C ambient. This is from the [On-Semi datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tip122-d.pdf)

[image]

Without a heatsink therefore, you are right on the edge, running at 100% of what the data sheet estimates to be allowable. Most experienced engineers would regard 100% as too close to design a product around for reliability, but if you are a hobbyist doing a one-off, then maybe you could take the risk of having no margin. If your device has a higher VCEsat, or the ambient is above 25°C, then you are running at more than 100%.

It won't need much of a heatsink to bring its temperature down and give you some margin. Alternatively, a MOSFET would give you a very low voltage drop, and switch 2 A with no trouble, especially as you have 12 V available for the gate.

Comment: @user263983 Thanks for your concern, citation added

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet - yes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TO-220